# Can't execute commands to my router python

Tags: python, ssh, router, paramiko

I am trying to make a project which in it i need to connect to the router from my code and recieve information from it -- > via python.

I have two routers : 
1. TP-LINK TL-WR841N
2. D-LINK DAP-1360

also, after reserching a lot about the subject i have a code which should work:

```
import paramiko
import sys
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('192.168.0.1',port=22,username = 'admin',password = 'admin')
try:
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('ls -l')
    print
    output = stdout.readlines()
    print '\n'.join(output)
except:
    print sys.exc_info()[1]
```

My code succed to connect to each one of my routers(I inserted the ip and login information properly for each router I tried using)
but failed to execute the commands im sending to him with the output: "channel closed."

I know that its something on the router side that I should fix - but i dont know how to do it and I couldn't find any answers about it. Can someone try and help?
thank you very much in advance.

Comment: can you connect via ssh without python?

Comment: "I know that its something on the router side that I should fix" If you're looking for help adjusting your router, you're on the wrong site. Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You might have better luck on [su], [sf], or maybe [unix.se].

Answer (score 0):

The routers you are mentioning are not supporting ssh access without a custom firmware like OpenWrt.